# How to properly inherit from classes with templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am pretty new to C++ and I have a doubt on templates and polymorphism. So, I was making basic funcs with templates but then I thought that I wanna work with classes and try to do some inheriting. So can someone properly guide me?

I have tried a little only and I just got errors. I really am new so I don't know a lot... :P

Here's the code I have typed till now:

```
template <class temp>
class car{
public:
    temp colour;
    temp *ptcs = &colour;
    temp setChar(temp a){
    *ptcs = a;
    }
    virtual void sayChar()=0;
};

class lambo : public car<string>{
public:
    void sayChar(){
    cout << "My characteristic : " << *ptcs << endl;
    }
};

class chiron : public car<string>{
public:
    void sayChar(){
        cout << "My characteristic : " << *ptcs << endl;
    }    
};

int main(){
}
```

I expect to inherit from car class and add more to it whilst being able to access and run code from both the derived classes in main()

Comment: What errors have you gotten?

Comment: Try to put something into `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the Pointer `ptcs`? There is no use for it. If you want to access private members of a base in a derived class, write a getter:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class car {
    T colour;
public:
    void setChar(T a) { colour = a; }
    T getChar() const { return colour; }
};

class lambo : public car<std::string> {
public:
    void sayChar() const {
        std::cout << "My characteristic : " << getChar() << '\n';
    }
};

class chiron : public car<std::string> {
public:
    void sayChar() const {
        std::cout << "My characteristic : " << getChar() << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    lambo foo;
    foo.setChar("red");
    foo.sayChar();

    chiron bar;
    bar.setChar("blue");
    bar.sayChar();
}
```

BTW, the search term you might be looking for is "Curiously recurring template pattern".

Comment: @user463035818 No, but the OP might still be interested in it.

Comment: hm of course. I misread the last sentence as that would be the term to get more details on the example

Comment: @user463035818 I think the example is pretty straight forward and the OP only got from one confusion to the next when he tried. After a few iterations people tend to begin throwing `*`s and `&`s onto the code randomly like spicing a soup ;)

Comment: Thanks @Swordfish for the answer, really appreciate it a lot! :)